# Php wordpress create custom function but it's slow

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm having a small problem in WordPress with a custom post type with a custom function query.

Here's the problem: write a custom php select function, and custom mysql connect function it's ok mysql connection is perfect, but site loading takes nearly a minute. I'm working on localhost...

```
function getSomeone($someone) {
    $sql = "select * from wp_posts where ID='{$someone}' and post_status='publish' limit 1";
    $af = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($af) {
        $list = mysql_fetch_array($af);
        return $list['post_title'];
    }
    else return false;
}
```

This query is working, but when I delete this query from the code, the page loads very quickly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it would be better to use WP_Query (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for this particular problem. You don't have to create custom conection and handling with securing your query.

Answer (score 0):

@marian0 that's correct ?

```
function getSomeone($someone) {
global $wpdb;
$mylink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID ='{$someone}'");
if ($mylink->post_title) {
return $mylink->post_title;
}
else return false;
}
```

is it correct ?